# Wait operation timeout while uploading through Excel Loader in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm uploading data from Excel file to database, MVC code reads the first record but on second record it throughs Time Out exception after adding user at "result"

```
 HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["students"];
            if ((file != null) && (file.ContentLength > 0) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string fileContentType = file.ContentType;
                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                var data = file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
            }
            var studentList = new List<RegisterViewModel>();
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(file.InputStream))
            {
                var currentSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets;
                var workSheet = currentSheet.First();
                var noOfCol = workSheet.Dimension.End.Column;
                var noOfRow = workSheet.Dimension.End.Row;

                for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
                {
                    var student = new RegisterViewModel();

                    var Fname = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString();
                    var Mname = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString();
                    var Lname = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 3].Value.ToString();

                    student.Name = Fname + " " + Mname + " " + Lname;
                    student.UserName = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 4].Value.ToString();
                     student.Email = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 5].Value.ToString();
                    student.Password = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 6].Value.ToString();
                    student.ConfirmPassword = workSheet.Cells[rowIterator, 7].Value.ToString();

                    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
                    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = student.UserName, Email = student.Email, Name = student.Name };
                    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, student.Password);
        if(result!="false")
        {
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer below and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Set `executionTimeout` property of httpRuntime tah in `web.config` as shown below:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" executionTimeout="30" />
</system.web>
```

Hope this helps...